# How to select data from database and return it via a WCF service?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dapper

I have a stored procedure that gets the `Filename` and `Path` (2 columns) from the database. I need to make a WCF service that returns the data into a format that any application that uses the service can use like a `List<string>` or something along the lines.

What's the best way to go about this (design and implementation-wise)?

Here's what I tried doing via Dapper ORM, but I'm not sure if it will work as intended.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> RetrieveIncompletedFiles(int type)
{
    try
    {
        using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
        {
            _connection.Open();
            var files = _connection.Query("SelectIncompletedFilesByFiletypeFromAsyncFileProcessingQueue", new { Filetype = type }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return files;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will almost certainly not work as expected. WCF wants to work against a known schema and a simple data type, typically a `List<SomeType>` where `SomeType` is a `public` class that is marked as a `[DataContract]` with `[DataMember]` elements. Fortunately, the dapper part of this should be as easy as:

```
 public List<SomeType> RetrieveIncompletedFiles (int type)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
    {
        return connection.Query<SomeType>("SelectIncompletedFilesByFiletypeFromAsyncFileProcessingQueue", new { Filetype = type }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. I'll give it a try. Is [DataContract] and [DataMember] analogous to a model in MVC?

Comment: @ygongdev sort of; they are the WCF (`DataContractSerializer`) mechanism for describing a type contract.

Comment: ok I made a "FilenameAndPath" (bad name I know) DataContract with 2 Datamembers (Filename, path)
How can I use this in let's say a console application? I'm trying the following
`List<FilenameandPath> blahblah = processor.RetrieveIncompletedFiles(filetype);` But obviously FilenameandPath is not recognized

Comment: there's no "obviously" there - that should work; are you sure it isn't just a typo (the `and` vs `And`, for example) - try pressing ctrl+. on the type to see if the IDE prompts you to fix the full name

Comment: Ah got it, I forgot `using AsyncFileProcessorService;` However, now I'm facing an interesting error, it says I can't `convert type 'string[]' to List<FilenameAndPath>`, but the return type from the service OperationContract is `List<FilenameAndPath>`?
Thanks for all your help so far

Comment: After a painful process dealing with reference and configuration issues, I finally got it to work. Your code was perfect for what I need on the programming side :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I finally got it working using the above code after struggling a lot with references on the client side. I had to configure the service reference settings. I had to change collection type from array to list and also uncheck "reuse reference", if I didn't uncheck, I got a lot of errors in Reference.cs, which made it a pain to work with on the client side.

`List<AsyncFileProcessorService.FilenameAndPath> filenameAndPaths = processor.RetrieveIncompletedFiles(filetype);`